# Exception in connecting to influxDb

Tags: java, influxdb

I try connect to influxDb in my Java code: 
`InfluxDB influxDB = InfluxDBFactory.connect("http://serverIp:8086", "admin", "admin");`

I get error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: okhttp3/Interceptor
    at org.influxdb.InfluxDBFactory.connect(InfluxDBFactory.java:47)
    at InfluxDbConnector.main(InfluxDbConnector.java:15)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: okhttp3.Interceptor
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 2 more
```

I use Maven and dependency in pom:

```
   <dependency>
        <groupId>org.influxdb</groupId>
        <artifactId>influxdb-java</artifactId>
        <version>2.7</version>
        <scope>system</scope>
        <systemPath>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/lib/influxdb-java-2.7.jar</systemPath>
    </dependency>
```

What okhttp3 dependency need add? Or how resolve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing the `com.squareup.okhttp3` dependency. Indeed, according to Maven Repository your InfluxDB dependency itself has a set of Compile dependencies.

Please see [here](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.influxdb/influxdb-java/2.7) for the complete list of those.